# Exactly one high card in a 6 card hand using simulations

Tags: c, probability, combinatorics

So I've got a probability problem that (out of pure boredom) I decided to try and solve using simulations.
Problem: What is the probability of drawing exactly one high card in a 6 card hand.

Now, this problem is specifically about some game that's played in my country so for some weird reason there are 21 high cards, but that's not important.

Solving this problem by hand, using basic combinatorics I got:
[image]

And now, here's the way I simulated it in C:

The main function:

```
int main(void)
{

    srand(time(0));
    int deck[52];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<21; i++) deck[i] = 1;
    for(i = 21; i<52; i++) deck[i] = 0;

    int n;
    printf("# of simulations: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int memo[52];

    int hits = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
      clear_memo(memo);
      hits += simulate(deck, memo);
    }
    printf("Result: %lf\n", (double)hits/n);


}
```

So the *deck* is an array of 52 numbers where the first 21 have the value 1 (high cards) and the other 31 elements have the value 0 (low cards).

The *memo* will be sent to the simulation function each time to keep track of which cards have already been drawn. The memo also gets reset every time using the *clear_memo* function which does nothing but set all the values to zero.

Then it calls the simulation functions and counts the hits.

Here's the simulation function:

```
int simulate(int * deck, int * memo){

  //I draw the first card separetly in order to initialize the had_high variable
  int index = ( rand() % 52 );
  int card = deck[index];
  int had_high = (card == 1);
  memo[index] = 1;

  //printf("%d ", index);

  int i = 1;
  while(i < 6){

    int draw = (rand() % 52);
    //printf("%d ", draw);
    if(memo[draw]) continue;

    index = draw;
    card = deck[index];
    memo[index] = 1;

    if(card){
        if(had_high) { //meaning there are 2 high cards, no hit
          //printf("\n");
          return 0;
        }
        had_high = 1; //if not, then this is the first high card
    }

    i++;
  }
  printf("\n");
  return had_high; //the function would've reached this point even if all the cards had been low
                   //therefore I return had_high instead of just 1

}
```

The simulation function itself works, I've tested it separately a lot of times and there seem to be no problems with it.

However, when I run the program with a high number of simulations (100k or 1m) the result is always approx. 0.175 which is not what I got with my by hand calculation.

I am reasonably certain that my by hand calculation is correct (but correct me if I'm wrong there as well).

If I'm right about the by hand calculations then there must be something wrong with how I simulated this event. One of my thoughts was that it had something to do with the *rand* function and how it's pseudo-random, but I really don't know as it is very hard to test anything that works with random numbers.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: 
As per request of klutt:

```
void clear_memo(int * memo){
  int i = 0;
  for(;i<52;i++) memo[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is the second term `32 / 51` when there are only `31` "low" cards?

Comment: Yeah, small mistake there. Still doesn't change the result much, and the program's output is still way off.

Comment: As well as Weather Vane's observation there are a couple of other problems. Firstly your calculation calculates the probability that the first card is the high, whereas any of the 6 cards can be the high card. So the probability is 6 times higher than your calculation. Secondly, using `int draw = (rand() % 52);` gives a bias to smaller numbers as the maximum random number is not divisible by 52.

Comment: Your simulation is off. You work with 52 cards, even though one is drawn each time, and you might draw the same card twice. Draw a card with a random index, copy the card at the top of the array into that slot, and reduce the number of cards. Count how many "high" cards were drawn.

Comment: @Dipstick 

First point: The order of the cards is irrelevant.
Second point: Is there any way to work around that?

Comment: @WeatherVane  When you draw a card you keep it, not return it. That's why  I said a 6-card hand.

Comment: You have `int had_high = (card == 1);` yet there are 21 "high" cards, not 1. Work on a table with a real deck of cards, then simulate that.

Comment: I still don't see your point. 

Maybe you're confusing the two operators? The initial value of had_high will be 1 IF the first card was high and it will be 0 IF the first card was low.

It's a short way of writing if(card == 1) had_high = 1; else had_high = 0;

Comment: Where is the code for `clear_memo`?

Comment: @klutt 
I don't know how to write code in comments but it's pretty much just:
for(i = 0; i<52; i++) memo[i] = 0;

Also tested by printing the memo array before each simulation, no problem there

Comment: @Koy Edit your question and add the code for completeness. Never (or at least very rarely) assume that the code you're not showing does not cause the problem.

Comment: It would work better to shuffle your array after marking the 21 high cards and then just take the first 6.

Comment: @klutt Done.

RetiredNinja What do you mean by 'better'? Shouldn't the probability be the same as long as the solution is correct in any way?

Comment: @Koy Less complex code. Maybe something like this: https://ideone.com/bGpfvc *shrug*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your calculation is wrong**

What you are calculating is the probability that the *first* card is high and *all of the rest* are low. Or at least it seams that you're trying to do so. You're slightly off. It should be `(21/52)*(31/51)*(30/50)*(29/49)*(28/48)*(27/47) = 0.02921...`

You should multiply this by 6, since the high card can appear anywhere. Then you have the probability for exactly one high, which is 0.17526

**`rand() % n` has a non-uniform distribution**

That being said, be aware that the random generator in C is not very good to use in this way. Depending on how you use it it can get a horrible distribution. If you are using C++, you can use:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine generator(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,51);
int index = distribution(generator);
```

In simulations like this, this may have a huge effect. In this case it had a small effect. I tested both the standard `rand()` method and the C++ variant and ran the simulation 4 times with 10 million iterations each time:

Using `rand() % 52`:

```
Result: 0.175141
Result: 0.175074
Result: 0.175318
Result: 0.175506
```

Using `distribution(generator)`:

```
Result: 0.175197
Result: 0.175225
Result: 0.175228
Result: 0.175293
```

As you can see, the deviation is smaller. So if accuracy matters, either consider switching to C++ and use those methods, or find a way to get a good distribution. And if you are doing a simulation to numerically calculate a probability, then it *does* matter.

Comment: Your results are the same because you are not seeding the generator. If you do then they vary. https://ideone.com/ml9Sox

Comment: The theoretical result is `0.17526475` and the average of your four `rand()` results is `0.17525975` however your supposedly better result of `0.175358` is consistently worse. Anyway, the question is neither about `rand` nor C++.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Fixed

Comment: @WeatherVane Fixed. And yes, you are right that the question is not about `rand`. However, if OP had basically the same problem but other numbers the distribution could definitely have been the problem. When you are trying to figure out a probability by simulation, a good distribution is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

My program gives the same result as yours - about 0.175

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int deck[52];
    int successes = 0;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(int run = 0; run < 100000; run++) {
        for(int n = 0; n<52; n++) {
            deck[n] = n;
        }
        int cards = 52;
        int highs = 0;
        for(int n=0; n<6; n++) {
            int index = rand() % cards;
            if(deck[index ] < 21) {
                highs++;
            }
            deck[index] = deck[--cards];
        }
        if(highs == 1) {
            successes++;
        }
    }
    printf("Probability of drawing exactly one high card = %f\n", successes / 100000.0);
}
```

But the combinatrics are wrong in two ways:

- There are only 31 "low" cards in the pack so the expression should be

```
21   31   30   29   28   27
__ . __ . __ . __ . __ . __   = 0.02921

52   51   50   49   48   47
```

- Secondly, any of the 6 draws can be a "high", not just the first, so
  multiply the chance by 6.

```
0.02921 * 6 = 0.1752
```